# How to put embedded document from one document into another document using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, express

What I'm trying to do should be straight forward but for some reason I'm having real difficulties figuring this out. I have the following Mongoose schemas (simplified).

```
var Status = new Schema({
    name : { type: String, required: true },
    description : { type: String }
});

var Category = new Schema({
    statuses : [Status], // contains a list of all available statuses
    // some other attributes
});

var Book = new Schema({
    statuses : [Status], // preferably this would not be an array but a single document, but Mongoose doesn't seem to support that
    // some other attributes
});
```

Now, I want to do the following:

1. Retrieve the Category document
2. Find a particular embedded Status document (based on request param)
3. Assign that particular embedded Status document to a particular Book document. I want to replace the existing Book status as at any given time there should only be one status set for a book.

Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
mongoose.model('Category').findOne({_id: id}, function(err, category){
    if(err) next(err);
    var status = category.statuses.id(statusId); // statusId available via closure
    book.statuses[0] = status; // book available via closure; trying to replace the existing status here.
    book.save(function(err){
        if(err) next(err);
        next();
    });
});
```

The above seems to run fine and I don't get any errors. However, the new status is not saved to the document. Next time I output the updated Book document, it will still have the old status. I debugged this and the find() methods as well as setting the status seems to be fine.

The only thing I can think of right now is that somehow the status value I'm assigning is not in the right format to be saved with Mongoose. Although, I would expect some kind of error message then.

Or maybe there is a better way to do all of this anyway?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are trying to copy an embedded document, which itself could have an ObjectId associated with it. Trying to save the duplicate `Status` within the `Book` would create two embedded documents with the same `ObjectId`. Try creating a new Status object and copying the fields.

It is hard to find docs on `ObjectsId`s for embedded documents, but they are mentioned here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/embedded-documents.html.